# Frama-C make error

Tags: frama-c

My environment setup is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x86_64:

After I "./configure" and followed by "make", errors as follows:

```
Ocamlc       src/plugins/value/gui_eval.cmi
Ocamlc       src/plugins/value/gui_eval.cmo
Ocamlc       src/plugins/value/gui_callstacks_filters.cmi
Ocamlc       src/plugins/value/gui_callstacks_filters.cmo
Ocamlc       src/plugins/value/register_gui.cmi
Ocamlc       src/plugins/value/register_gui.cmo
File "src/plugins/value/register_gui.ml", line 224, characters 26-52:
Error: Unbound module GtkButtonProps
make: *** [src/plugins/value/register_gui.cmo] Error 2
```

Full log is given here:

http://pastebin.com/7D0KRZh3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 apparently uses `liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev-2.16.0`. For some reason (which is not really explained in [the corresponding debian repository](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-ocaml-maint/packages/lablgtk2.git/commit/?id=785523ba548341ef31832e82142f5c619219d1eb)) this `.deb` seems to include a patch to specifically not install some parts of the library. The newer version (`2.18.3`) did remove this patch, but it will only be available for 16.04 as far as I can tell from looking at [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lablgtk2). You might be able to [pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) the package to `2.18.3`, but I guess questions on how to it belong to https://askubuntu.com.

Another option would be to use [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org) to manage ocaml-specific packages (I'd advise against using the `opam` package from Ubuntu 14.04 as it is itself a bit old, opam being a pretty fast-evolving beast). The `lablgtk` package from `opam` does not suffer from the issue mentioned above, and you can in fact directly install the latest `frama-c` version from `opam`.

Comment: I will make it Ubuntu 16.04 then, thanks for the notes, appreciate very much :-).   Great timesaver.